# What measures i can take to stop users being able to clone my app?

Tags: android

I have one mobile app, there are chances that the user will try to make multiple instances of the same mobile app. I want to keep some guard so that I can ensure "one device one user " policy.  I saw  Parallel Space that can clone app inside the same device.

Comment: I don't think you can stop users using another app (that clones yours) but I am sure you can determine wether your users do so or not by using logic within your code

Comment: How do i they are running  more than two app from same device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not really simple. But the easiest way to do this is reading the MAC address that is an unique address. But keep in mind that it can be changed. 
You can find something here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids